# Creating 50 threads to connect to a server to load test

Tags: java, multithreading

Using java, how can I create 50 threads to make a simple http get request to a particular URL?

I want each thread to make maybe 100-1k requests.

Is it possible to guarantee that all these threads connect at the same time?

I basically want something similiar to Apache bench, but written in java so I can learn some java along the way.

So the input would be:

```
1. # of requests in total
2. # of threads to use
3. url to make a request with
```

**Update**
I guess to keep track of request statistics i.e. how long a particular request took on average I would need a global collection that is thread-safe?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some (incomplete) code:

```
public class Test {

    private static int REQUESTS;
    private static int NUM_THREADS; 
    private static String URL;
    private static ArrayList<Statistic> result = new ArrayList<Statistic>();

    private static class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

        private int tid;

        public ThreadTask(int tid) {            
            this.tid = tid;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Statistic stat = new Statistic();
            for(int i = 0; i < REQUESTS; i++) {
                // make request
                // add results to stat
            }
            result.add(tid, stat); // no need to lock because each 
                                   // thread writes to a dedicated index 
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // take command line arguments
        REQUESTS = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        NUM_THREADS = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        URL = args[2];
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUM_THREADS];

        // start threads
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadTask(i));
            threads[i].start();
        }

        // wait for threads to finish
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class `Statistic` is something defined by you to collect whatever statistics you want.
Of course, many improvements can be suggested, this is just what I wrote in 5 minutes. :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a combination of a ThreadPoolExecutor for scheduling threads and a CyclicBarrier for activating all threads at the same time.  Both classes are in the java.util.concurrency package.

Comment: thanks great, is it allot of code to do this? any code snippet suggestions?

Comment: so I take it you didn't even look at the documentation for CyclicBarrier.  Otherwise you would've found an example right there.

Answer (score 1):

I have used JMeter for this purpose. http://jmeter.apache.org.
There is a little bit of learning curve for the tool.
In Jmeter, threadgroup allows you to use number of threads, ramp-up period and loop count.
You can create an HTTP request and view results using view results in a Tree or Table. Hope this helps.